# Error when exchanging code for Oauth

Tags: google-drive-api

Suddenly, I am getting an error during the Oauth process, after my app has been given permission for access by the user and a authorization code is delivered to my redirect url. I've been using the same code for a couple weeks now, and it has been working fine. I'm pretty certain I haven't made any changes.

Is there an issue with Google Drive API today?

The error occurs here in Python code here:

```
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(authorization_code)
```

Error message:

```
FlowExchangeError: Invalid response 400.
```

The entire exchange_code method as copied from Google example:

```
def exchange_code(authorization_code):
  """Exchange an authorization code for OAuth 2.0 credentials.

  Args:
    authorization_code: Authorization code to exchange for OAuth 2.0
                    credentials.
  Returns:
    oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance.
  Raises:
    CodeExchangeException: an error occurred.


  """

  logging.debug(authorization_code);

  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION, ' '.join(SCOPES))

  flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI


  try:
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(authorization_code)
    return credentials
  except FlowExchangeError, error:
    logging.error('An error occurred: %s', error)
    raise CodeExchangeException(None)
```

Using Oauth Playground, I get the following error response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Ok
Status: 400
Content-length: 37
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 10 Aug 2012 03:23:54 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json
 Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
```

Any ideas why this would start happening when the code was working for weeks as it is now?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the code working again. I reverted the GAE app version to my prior version. Oauth exchange_code worked again. Then I took it back to the current version  on GAE, with no changes to the code whatsoever, and it continues to work.

So the oauth process did stop working when I recently created new version in GAE with no changes to the code. For what it's worth.....

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP response code 400 means that your request is somehow invalid and there should be a more descriptive error message telling you what is wrong.

Perhaps the Python library is hiding the complete message, I'd recommend you to try the same request with the OAuth 2.0 Playground and compare it with yours:

https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Thanks Claudio, I have edited the question to show the response out OAuth 2.0 Playground

Comment: Can you also add the request? Feel free to remove sensitive details

Comment: I don't know how to show the actual request, other than the line that is failing, which is listed first above: credentials = flow.step2_exchange(authorization_code). I assume that 'flow' is defined in one of the imports: from oauth2client.client import FlowExchangeError.
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError.
from oauth2client.client import Credentials... can you tell me how to see the actual request sent?

Comment: All the code I am using here is from examples from Google documentation.

Comment: while I was giving information about how to get more details about the error, I don't see how this question was answered. Does anyone know why, based on the question, I would suddenly be getting an error message in code that did not change and worked for weeks?